# Looking for comparable tooltip capability for AngularJS that cluetip gave me

Tags: angularjs, cluetip

I've gotten the code from the post [Angular-ui tooltip with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029676/angular-ui-tooltip-with-html) working but it's capabilities are not near what cluetip gave me.  Things like not having automatically aligning based on screen position and other options make it not very useful for me.  You can see the capability I'm wanting with Angular when you hover over the details buttons on the page http://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/session

Is there anything comparable to cluetip in the angular world? has anyone done an integration with angular and cluetip?

Answer (score 0):

you could mod a popover element from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ with css to do the same

Comment: I did look at that but it seems it's capabilities don't compare to cluetip (or as I think it is now, themeroller with tooltip).  things like automatically figuring out the position of the tooltip seem quite complex.