# ngBindHtml different result than $sce.parseAsHtml in template that uses angularUI

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, html-entities

***Edit***: Solution found! See bottom of question for explanation.

I have a directive sfNgFieldWrapper that contains a tooltip that I got from angularjUI ui-bootstrap.

The text of the tooltip is set with `tooltip="{{ttpText}}"`.

The problem is that the text contains html entities and these entities are not translated to the correct character.
I can't use ng-bind-html but I've checked and when I do use it on a span the text for the tooltip is correctly transformed.
However, I can't use span and ng-bind-html since I need to use tooltip.

To fix this predicament I thought I would use `$sce.pareAsHtml`. The problem is that the html entities are not correctly transformed to characters!

I use it in my directive link function like so:

```
scope.ttpText = $sce.parseAsHtml(scope.ttpText);
```

Why doesn't parseAsHtml work while ng-bind-html does?

I can't put the parseAsHtml inside scope.$watch because that triggers a loop.

TrustAsHtml doesn't work either.

The tooltip function binds the content like so:

```
$document.find( 'body' ).append( tooltip );
```

## Solution

After looking into the code of ui-bootstrap I started search stackoverflow specifically for it and I found a question with a similar issue and solution!
[Angular-ui tooltip with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029676/angular-ui-tooltip-with-html)

Stupid me could also just have checked the AngularUI guide:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

The solution is simple, I can just add `-html-unsafe` after `data-tooltip`.

Comment: How do you add `ttpText` to the DOM?

Comment: My directive has an isolated scope where my ttpText is defined as ttpText: '@'.

Comment: You need to share more code. Also, when I am asking how you add `ttpText` to the DOM, I am asking what function are you using: `.text()` or `.html()`?

Comment: could you try `attrs.$observ(attrs.ttpText, function(n){ //changed value here})`

Comment: I've added extra info and more code, and I will try what pankajparkar suggested.

Comment: Solution found. Thank you for the responses though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I also updated the question for maximum visibility.

After looking into the code of ui-bootstrap I started search stackoverflow specifically for it and I found a question with a similar issue and solution! Angular-ui tooltip with HTML

Stupid me could also just have checked the AngularUI guide: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

The solution is simple, I can just add *-html-unsafe* after *data-tooltip*.